# Tentar verificar se um dia está inserido num intervalo entre duas datas

Tags: php

Boas, tenho uma função que me guarda numa array os dias entre duas datas. 
De seguida, quero verificar se um dado dia pertence ao intervalo e crio um foreach que me percorre o array com as datas todas e, no caso de a data estar inserida, ele dá um echo de '1'.

A questão é que ele nunca me retorna 1 mesmo quando a data corresponde a um valor do array.

O meu código é o seguinte:

```
$data_inicial = new DateTime(implode('-', array_reverse(explode('/', '10/05/2010'))));
$data_final = new DateTime(implode('-', array_reverse(explode('/', '07/06/2010'))));

while ($data_inicial <= $data_final) {
    $datasint[] = $data_inicial->format('d/m/Y') . '<br />' . PHP_EOL;
    $data_inicial->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 days'));
}


foreach ($datasint as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == '25/05/2010') {
        echo '1';
    }
}
```

Alguem consegue perceber onde está o erro? Se quiserem copiem o código e tentem por vocês mesmos!

Comment: Você está concatenando `<br />` nas datas, então dentro do `foreach` os valores são `10/05/2010<br />`, `11/05/2010<br />`, `25/05/2010<br />` etc.

Comment: muito obrigado!

Comment: Se for só para verificar, você não precisa criar um array com todos os dias, basta verificar se a data em questão é maior que a data inicial e menor que a data final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o **hkotsubo** disse, você está concatenando `<br />` em cada valor do array. E no momento de realizar a comparação com a string acontece da seguinte forma:

```
foreach ($datasint as $key => $value) {
    if ('25/05/2010<br />' == '25/05/2010') {
        echo '1';
    }
}
```

Basta apenas remover a concatenação.

```
while( $data_inicial <= $data_final ) {
    $datasint[]= $data_inicial->format( 'd/m/Y' );
    $data_inicial->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString( '1 days' ));
}
```

Méritos da resposta ao **hkotsubo**, respondi aqui para facilitar na busca da resposta.